# bool and int types in boolean contexts

Tags: python, boolean, logical-operators

I have this code in a *boolean context*:

```
True and False or 2
```

Output: 2

The type check for this expression resulted in `int`.

Next, I modified the code to:

```
True and False or True
```

Output : `True`
And the type check for this expression resulted in `bool`

- Why is the output in the 1st code `2`?
- Shouldn't the expression evaluate to a boolean value ?
  If not so, Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, when using 'and' and 'or', the expression evaluates using the objects involved, instead of using Booleans as in many other languages.

So:

```
1 and 2 will evaluate to 2
1 or 2 will evaluate to 1 (short-circuit)
1 and "hello" will evaluate to "hello"
```

... and so on

If you want the Boolean, just surround the whole expression with bool(..)

Further reading:
http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 3):

All you need to know here is the definition of [`OR` operand](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or).Based on python documentation :

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

So since the [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of `or` is lower than `and` your expression evaluated as following :

```
(True and False) or 2
```

Which is equal to following :

```
False or 2
```

Thus based on preceding documentation the result would be the value of right object which is 2.

Comment: do you mean [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: I get that part. My question was about the output and not the method of evaluation. Why is the output `2` and not `True`?

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi It's the logic but as  mentioned in documentation python instead of True return the value.

Answer (score 0):

When you said `True and False` it is evaluate to `False`.
Then you have `False or 2` which will evaluate to `2`
Now `True and False or True` will evaluate to `True` but the last `True` in your expression. This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

```
>>> True and False
False
>>> False or 2
2
>>>
```

The output is `2` not `True` because `True and False or 2` is like

```
var = (True and False)
if var:
    print(var)
else:
    print(2)
```

which yields

```
2
```

because `True and False` will always evaluate to `False`

Comment: I get the method of evaluation. My question is why is the output `2` and not `True`?

Comment: Is this really so ? To be honest, I find it quite weird

Comment: Can you share any link for further reads along this school of thought

Answer (score 0):

I think you are clear with the operator precedence between `and` and `or.`According to Python documentation, the **object** is returned.

```
>>> 1 and 2
```

will return `2` according to the shorcut evaluation.
and so on.